# What is the mistake in this JQuery Ajax GetJSON Call?

Tags: jquery, ajax, getjson

My script is

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        $.getJSON("Sample.js", function (data) { var sample = data.one; $("#html").html(sample); })
        });
```

And Sample.js contains

```
{ one: "one" }
```

When i run this code i get only blank screen. how do i get "one" as output?

When i am running with $.get the same code produces {one:"one"} as output.

Comment: Can you show your markup? Is there an element with id `html`?

Comment: @RGraham yes,there is a div with id html. when i am using $.get i am getting {one:"one"} in htnl tag. how do i get "one" by $.getJSON?

Comment: You file name ends with `.js`, so your server is probably serving the file with a mimetype of `text/javascript` instead of `application/json`. jQuery is possibly trying to execute the script rather than deliver it to your code.

Comment: @MikeW oh... i am new to jquery-ajax. how to solve this issue and how to get json from .html or .aspx file... any good links?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your json is invalid. Try with :

```
{ "one": "one" }
 // ^----- this has to be quoted
```

You can check the validity of your json here : http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: yes... have to quote and i get the output. but Visual Studio shows warning ----> "Expected ;" in the space of ":". Do not know why it is showing so.

Answer (score 0):

You are using getJSON method..so obviously the o/p will be an JSON object..so inorder to get in the form of a string,..call a call back function and convert the JSON response to String format

Your JSON should be some thing like:

```
 {  "one": "Singular sensation",  "two": "Beady little eyes",  "three": "Little birds pitch by my doorstep" }
```